# How to approach storing and comparing returned values in python

Tags: python

complete rookie with python here. I'm wondering what type of data structure and how to approach what I'm trying to do.

I have a few functions that all return an integer. I need to store these values and compare them to themselves to see if they've changed when calling the functions a second time. How should I approach this? pointing me in the right direction is very appreciated.

All I have currently is calling the three functions in succession:

```
self.checkAlarmVolume()
self.checkSpeakerVolume()
self.checkMusicVolume()
```

Comment: How many times you want to compare the values? And when you are you going to compare them?

Comment: I only need to compare them once. I grab the values, reboot the device, so there's a sleep next, check that the device is booted, then compare them again after a device reboot. I've been playing with an array to do this, but not sure if that's the best option.

Comment: If you are just going to compare them once, why you don't just store it in 2 variables?

Comment: I guess I don't understand how to take the returned values and put them all into 1 variable. I'm pretty green to this, eep. I do grasp using two lists and comparing those like your example below, but sounds like im over complicating things.

Comment: Try just storing them into variables, let's say `a1` and `a2` (as the example I gave), so you will compare `a1` with `a2`. I think you may want to do this 3 times, for each function you have. Doing this is not necessary to use lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
a1 = self.checkAlarmVolume()
...
a2 = self.checkAlarmVolume()

if (a1 != a2)
    ...
```

Another way, if you want to store many values, you could use a `list`:

```
a_list = []
a_list.append(self.checkAlarmVolume())
...
a_list.append(self.checkAlarmVolume())

if (a_list[0] != a_list[1])
    ...
```